# Dispose() is not stopping consuming in Spring Reactor

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I am trying to consume data for aggregation using WebFlux and WebClient. It must be stopped when a condition is met. But calling dispose() seems not stopping my subscription. I expect the flow jumps on onComplete() but it is not. Any idea to resolve that?

```
    public void consume() {  
      Flux<Employee> employeeFlux = client.get()  
       .uri("/employees")  
       .retrieve()  
       .bodyToFlux(Employee.class);  
    
      disposable = employeeFlux .subscribe(content -> onNext(content), error -> onError(error),  
      () -> onComplete());  
    }  

   private void onNext(Employee employee) {  
      //Collect-process the data  

      if (condition()) {  
         logger.info("Consuming stopping!");  
         disposable.dispose();  
      }  
    }  

   private void onComplete() {  
   
      // Aggregate the collected data 
      
      logger.info("Consuming completed!");  
   }
```

I debugged it and saw that disposable.dispose() hits. But after that, neither breakpoints at onNext nor onComplete  is being hit. I did't understand what is going on.I expected the flow jumps to onComplete method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The disposable received when you `subscribe()` does not serve to cancel the reactive stream, but only the *subscription* created for your subscriber.

It means that the disposable is not directly responsible for stopping the flux, but to disconnect your subscriber from the flow, i.e. stop receiving events (on next, completion, etc.).

Now, disposing your subscriber **might** also cancel the flow, but this is not guaranteed. For examples, some types of *hot streams* (i.e. live streams) would keep living even if all subscribers are retired.

For your use-case, if you want to cancel the flux upon a specific event, but still want to receive completion signal in your subscriber, you can use a shorting operation on the FLux, like [takeWhile(Predicate)](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#takeWhile-java.util.function.Predicate-) or [takeUntil(Predicate)](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#takeUntil-java.util.function.Predicate-).

Here is a simple example that stops a flow once 5 values have been received:

```java
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.util.Loggers;

public class DisposeSubscriber {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Predicate<Long> condition = value -> value < 5;
        var barrier = new CountDownLatch(1);
        Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(100))
                .takeWhile(condition)
                .subscribe(v -> System.out.println("next: "+v),
                           err -> System.out.println("error: "+err.getMessage()),
                           () -> {
                                System.out.println("Completed");
                                barrier.countDown();
                           }
                );

        barrier.await();
    }
}
```

The program output shows that subscriber have well received the flow completion signal:

```
next: 0
next: 1
next: 2
next: 3
next: 4
Completed
```

Comment: takeWhile() worked fine. What about doFinally() callback? I have seen that it is triggered after dispose as well. Is there difference betweek takeUntil() and dispose() + doFinally()?

Comment: takeWhile is part of the flow, so when you do not subscribe to it yourself (when you return a flux that will be consumed later by another user/component), your stop condition is embedded in it. But apart from that, dispose() + doFinally() should also work, it is a matter of how you prefer organizing logic/responsability across your code, I think.